# Permanova for microbial ecology using adonis (R): should I include block?

Tags: distance, permutation-test, manova, ecology

I know this is a very basic question, but I have been quite unsuccessful in finding a good solution to the following issue.

First the data. My spreadsheet is too big, so here is a fictional example:

```
ORGAN   FARM    SP1 SP2 SP3 SP4 SP5 SP6
Mouth   CityA   41  2   45  1   68  33
Stomach CityA   63  85  56  48  82  52
Intestines  CityA   62  73  15  88  42  64
Mouth   CityB   89  8   84  17  76  97
Stomach CityB   97  25  65  8   62  25
Intestines  CityB   8   17  70  60  24  85
Mouth   CityC   88  32  0   12  39  41
Stomach CityC   91  15  91  10  57  55
Intestines  CityC   51  14  85  75  47  33
Mouth   CityD   20  18  82  12  39  81
Stomach CityD   31  86  19  28  79  36
Intestines  CityD   56  46  34  44  72  72
Mouth   CityE   78  82  9   1   13  80
```

In each city, the microbiota of different organs of pigs were sampled. The types of microbes found are listed as "SP1" and so on. Next, I calculated a dissimilarity matrix (bray-curtis, with vegdist in R).

I want to know what explains variation in the communities sampled - the organ where they were sampled or the city where they were located? If my matrix of dissimilarity is called "dist", then, what of the following is the most appropriate model for a PERMANOVA analysis? Using adonis in R:

```
dist ~ organ*farm      #no block or nest notation
dist ~ organ*farm, strata = farm      #farm as block
dist ~ organ/farm       #organs nested in farm
```

Is it correct to say that organs are nested within farm? Does nested information remain after permutation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have got no answers so far, but I have only got 15 views so far. I was wondering if there is anything I should do to make this question more visible or easier to answer. Perhaps I should simplify my example and question?